# Fresh install of TeXLive 2021 didn't set system variables Linux

Tags: texlive, update

After installing texlive2021 I noticed that "tex" still referred to the 2020 version which I have removed after installing texlive2021.
I thought a restart would help, but now it just offers me to install texlive-binaries using the package manager.

I am thinking about purging everything and reinstalling, but I thought I might ask here first.
Commands no longer working are:

```
tex, pdftex, latex, xetex, xelatex, kpsewhich, tlmgr
```

/usr/local/texlive/ contains 2021 as expected.

Comment: Which shell are you using? Probably you need to set the PATH correctly somewhere. Try to issue `which pdflatex` on a terminal to debug...

Comment: Last time I installed TeX live on a Linux machine I had to set the PATH manually. I don't know if the installer has an option to do that automatically. Did you explicitly tell the installer to set your path? If so, what exactly did you do? Our go-to guide https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/35864 recommends to set the PATH in `~/.profile` (but I think I always end up using something else, so `sudo` works properly ...).

Comment: the installation instructions explictly say that you need to set the PATH after the install.  https://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html   section **Post-install: setting PATH**

Comment: Thanks David. Would you mind making it an Answer so I can accept it? It was totally my fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The installation instructions explictly say that you need to set the PATH after the install.

https://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html

section **Post-install: setting PATH**